# Display Modal Window in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal component defined as per Basic example below:
 https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

My challenge is to display it on click of a link declared in other components all across the application.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) of your component. Something like this

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { showModal: false };
  }

  displayModal() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
  }

  render() {
    return <Child showModal={this.state.showModal} onButtonClick={this.displayModal.bind(this)}
  }
}
```

And for the child:

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.props.onButtonClick}>
        <Modal open={this.props.showModal} onHide={...}>
          ...
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In my parent class, I have this code :
      displayModal(){
  var confirmModal = new ExampleModal();
  confirmModal.handleShow();
  }
Example modal class is same as Basic Example here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Now, its giving error as :
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op

Comment: You do not instantiate a React component like this. You have to render it somewhere controlling its props, as I did in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

import  modal component  having modal code in your topmost component hierarchy and store some modalStatus in redux state(if you are using redux)
and show or unshow modal depending on the modalStatus value in redux state.

if not using redux,any other state manager will have similiar paradigm

If not using any state manager , then most probably your application is small, just keep the modalStatus in state of parent component and pass callback to various component